# react-infinite-scroll doesn't stop invoking loadmore prop function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I have configured my code InfiniteScroll from react-infinite-scroll sample here: https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller/blob/master/docs/src/index.js

My code is like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  loadItems = (pagingState) => {
    let query = `/api/v1/news?pagingState=${pagingState}`;
    axios.get(query, { 
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token')
      },
    }).then(async (response) => {
      if(!response.data.rows.length) {
        this.setState((state, props) => ({
          hasMoreItems: false
        }));
      }

      var encodeURLPagingState = encodeURIComponent(response.data.pagingState)

      await this.setState({
        pagingState: encodeURLPagingState,
        offset: this.state.offset+15,
        allNews: [...this.state.allNews, ...response.data.rows]
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(`1st axios catch! = `,err)
    }); 
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ul>
        <InfiniteScroll
          pageStart={0}
          loadMore={this.loadItems(this.state.pagingState)}
          hasMore={this.state.hasMoreItems}
          loader={<div>Looading...</div>}
          useWindow={false}
        >
          {items}
        </InfiniteScroll>) 
      </ul>
  }
```

I looked at the issues, i tried this already: `loader={<div style={{ clear: 'both' }}>Loading...</div>}` I am also sure every items node has unique key, help?

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error in render with the closing `)` which is before the `</ul>` closing tag.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If yes then can you please tell how?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to use a Promise object. The syntax is as follows:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   ... make your fetch calls here ...
   resolve();
}
```

This will prevent subsequent fetch calls till the promise is resolved i.e. resolve() is called.

For more, refer here [MDN Promise object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)  and here [helpful tutorial](https://www.fullstackreact.com/30-days-of-react/day-15/) .

Cheers.